# how to avoid text overflow in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap. I wrote following HTML:

```
<div class="span4">
   <span class="row-fluid hideOverflow">
   @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "JumpLinks", @style = "font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;" })
   </span>
</div>
```

The `CSS` for the `hideOverflow` class is:

```
.hideOverflow
{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

But it is showing me result as:
[image]

Then I changed 'row-fluid' to `span12` and then it is showing the following result:

[image]

Why is my `hideOverFlow` class not working with the `row-fluid` class?

What do I need to change in order to get the same result as the `row-fluid` class?

Comment: i think reduce the size of that div or apply padding-right to it... also remove row-fluid it make no sense to apply it...

Answer (score 16):

make the html structure like this...

```
<div class="span4">
   <span class="hideOverflow">@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "JumpLinks", @style = "font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;" })</span>
</div>
```

The CSS:-

```
.hideOverflow
{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: i have other span elements in parent div. So I can not use your suggestion.

Comment: main thing is that you have to provide the text-overflow container whether its a span or div with some width... may be in %... see the updates...

Comment: Why should it be applied directly to the span? I tried to apply it on the div, but that does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Of course the question title is broad... it'll depend on `Bootstrap`'s structure you're working with since it may have CSS rules which can interfere with your code.

In my situation I have a structure with `row-fluid`, `span#`s and `label` CSS classes like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">    
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="standard-placeholder" style="display: none;">
            @Html.Label(Localization.Title)
            <span class="label label-warning standard-description"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Taking advantage of the code provided by [SaurabhLP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15308291/114029) I used this shorten `CSS` version which did it for me:

```
.standard-description {
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
}
```

It correctly places an `ellipsis` in the text inside the `span` when the title is very long.

As a plus: if you want to make the text break line, then you can try this `CSS` instead:

```
.standard-description {

    white-space:pre-line;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using row-fluid in the correct place , thats why you are seeing  the issue. Row-fluid creates a row inside which you can create columns using span classes , and since row-fluid uses percentage it will expand to fill all available horizontal space when on a large screen, and shrink columns to keep them from vertically stacking as the screen resizes.

So the basic principle is to use row-fluid this way :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span4">
     <span class="hideOverflow">@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "JumpLinks", @style = "font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;" })</span>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thats why when you removed row-fluid and replaced it with span12 your issue was resolved .
Also the best practice is to assign span with a class with property of width :100% , like :

```
.text-span{
         {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Then use it in your code like :

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">
         <span class=" text-span hideOverflow">@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "JumpLinks", @style = "font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;" })</span>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Avoid using span12 inside a span4 .

Answer (score 1):

Add word-wrap: break-word in your DIV. Write this:

```
.span4{
    width: 700px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```